# How can I create an instance of the default GlobalResourceProvider?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, localization, webforms

I need to create a custom LocalResourceProvider in ASP.NET. It seems that I have to create a custom ResourcePRoviderFactory for this. However, that means also returning an IResourceProvider from CreateGlobalResourceProvider (`null` doesn't work).

I can't find what the frameworks default ResourceProvider is, so I can return that, so I don't have to create my own.

(Bonus points for the default LocalResourceProvider too, since all I need to change is virtualPath, so being able to create an instance of the default but pass my own pass will make things easier).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution. It's not nice, though:

```
// HACK: The default provider is internal, so we have to use reflection to create it, so we can steal it's behaviour.
string typeName = "System.Web.Compilation.ResXResourceProviderFactory, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a";
defaultFactory = (ResourceProviderFactory)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(typeName));
```